# How this keyword work in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, scope, this

I am not able to understand the **this** keyword in Node.js

consider the code

```
var a=6
function fun(){
    var a=2;
    console.log(this);
    console.log(this.a);//undefined
    console.log("****",a);//2
}

fun();
```

In this **a** is defined at global scope and inside function **fun()**.According to Scope rule of JavaScript  **a** should return 2 and **this.a** should return 6 but in this code **this.a** is **undefined** where as **a** is 2.

Please explain the meaning of **this** in node.js and how it differs from **this** of javaScript.

Also, explain how to access the global **a** inside the function **fun()**

Comment: If you declare a function using the `function` keyword, `this` refers to the function. However, you declared `a` as a variable in the function scope, not as a property. Please refer to this question : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3127429/how-does-the-this-keyword-work

Comment: What in browser JavaScript would be the global scope in Node is the *module* scope. Leaving off `var` when initializing the global `a` (as in the code you initially posted) will actually work, because that will create a globally-scoped `a`.

Comment: *"In this a is defined at global scope"* Not if this code is inside a module. *"According to Scope rule of JavaScript [...] this.a should return 6"* Only if the code is executed in *global scope* in non-strict mode. But that's not the case for node modules.